# Teaching mathematics in Portugal

Tags: job-hunting, portugal

**I little bit of my profile**

I'm a brazilian and I have a bachelor's degree in mathematics and I'm finishing a master degree in pure mathematics (algebraic geometry). I can speak English, German, French (I've already lived there), Spanish and Portuguese (Of course). I'm a math professor (non-permanent) at a high education institute in Brasil. My prospectives in my country are great, there are a lot of jobs here for teachers and college professors, because Brasil is a developing country which lacks high professionals.

**My question**

Before getting a well-paying permanent job in my country as a professor (and get married, be fat and die) I would like to have some work experiences in another countries. I love to travel and know new cultures.  So, are there ways for me to teach in school in Portugal? I think Portugal would be easier for me because of the language.

Comment: I am not sure I can make heads or tails of what you're asking.  The only question you have posed has an answer of **yes**.  Otherwise it is unclear what it is that you're asking.

Comment: If you choose to do a PhD you could aim for a research/academic career. That's not easy but you get to travel (for conferences of course but also chasing 1-2 years post-doc appointments). People who are trying to start a family actually complain about that aspect of academic careers but it could be a plus for you.

Comment: @Karlson so if the answer is yes, how can I do that? do you know any program to teach abroad to a non English native speaker? this is what my question about.

Comment: @Gala yes, I've already thought about this. The problem is I don't know if I will be a researcher in my area.  On the other hand, someone with a master or a PHD degree in pure mathematics is overqualified to be a teacher in schools, even if you consider countries with a high level of  basic education.

Comment: @user26832 Then you should focus the question on this rather then on the side stories.  In addition focus on a particular country or a region and a level for which you want to teach mathematics.  School level is one thing, university orca colledge is quit another.  As it stands the question is too broad and unclear.

Comment: @Karlson is it ok, now?

Comment: If you just want to have experience in other countries then maybe you can also work other jobs instead of teaching in a high-ed institution, which normally requires PhD? If you are not sure you want to do research then you won't necessarily like teaching in such an institution anyways. Also I'm a kind of surprised - Does a master degree suffice to land you the best of higher-ed jobs in Brazil? In China unless you earned a PhD from a very top university in the world it's basically impossible. As a "professor" in Brazil I suppose you'll still have to do researches?

Comment: @XiangJi I wouldn't say this kind of institutions are high-end. I'm just saying that I can have a very comfortable life here in a tenured job. In Brazil there are some institutions which you don't need to do research. Institutions which the focus is _teaching_ future engineers and computer scientists. I think americans call this kind of institutions of "colleges". Yes, I don't have problems to teach in high schools.

Comment: @XiangJi Professor for me is someone who teaches undergraduate students. Maybe my definition is not correct, I'm sorry. Speaking of Brazilians jobs, here is a huge growing country (like China) which lacks qualified people in some regions. So if you live in these regions, even without a master degree you can teach in a "college" in a permanent position.